# Extracting number from address string using QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, expression, string, address-parsing

I have a table with addresses and I need to extract only the number from the attributes.

The format is as follows:

| address |
| --- |
| VALLEY VIEW HOUSE, 36 HIGH VIEW, USHAW MOOR, DH7 7QQ |
| 35 HIGH VIEW, USHAW MOOR, DURHAM, DH7 7QQ |
| DURHAM ROAD, USHAW MOOR, DURHAM, DH7 7LF |

If I use `regexp_substr("address", '(\\d+)')` it will correctly extract the number from the first 2 cases but on the 3rd one it will extract the number from the postcode *BUT* I do not want that to be extracted.

Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Correct, the postcode format is 2characters+1number+whitespace+1number+2characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to add regex word boundaries ([`\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)) to extract your numbers:

```
regexp_substr("address", '\\b\\d+\\b')
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this expression:

```
regexp_substr(
    replace( 
        "address",
        regexp_substr("address",'\\d\\s\\d') ,
        ''
    ),
    '(\\d+)'
)
```

[image]